# Eclipse doesn't allow content assist for xhtml files

Tags: eclipse

Before I start let me tell I have gone through all the related questions in stackoverflow and tried every solution but still I cant ctrl+click on the xhtml files to navigate easily as I can with my java files. My version is:-
Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
Also, I have checked JavaServer Faces in Project facets.
Please help

Comment: Ctrl+Click on *what* in a xhtml file? That should navigate to where? Is the file correctly set up as a Facelet? Does it not work on the current release (juno's over two years old)?

Comment: for example I have this:-
disabled="#{notificationTemplateBean.editUpdate}"
Now I want to ctrl+click on editUpdate and that should take me to the function in notificationTemplateBean.java

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/features/cdi.html) to enable such features.

[image]